# Jquery Modular - extend functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I want. I have a jquery module pattern which has few functions. Some of the functions to be repeated in different files.

I have designed simple javascript games for learning purpose of jquery.

```
var myGame = {
init: function( settings ) {
myGame.config = {
        items: [],
        seconds: 60,
        settings: settings
    };
$.extend( myGame.config, settings );
},

start: function() {
},
reset: function() {
},
...
```

}

Let it be game.js

**start**, **reset** are functions which will be used in all the games.
If the game is about maths calculation, i want a calculate.js which can extend these functions(game.js) and calculate.js will have its own calculation functions

How do I achieve this?

Comment: have you heared about object inheritance ?

Comment: yes, in java, php. But i have no idea in jquery :(